# How to retrieve files from the isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

how do i allow this code to retrieve the files from a directory? For example, my directory name is "Folder Name":

```
private ObservableCollection<FileItem> LoadFiles()
{
    ObservableCollection<FileItem> files = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>();

    foreach (string filePath in this.Store.GetFileNames())
        files.Add(new FileItem { FileName = filePath });
    return files;
}
```

EDIT:

I've tried this, and it still isn't working:

```
 private ObservableCollection<FileItem> LoadFiles()
        {
            ObservableCollection<FileItem> files = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>();


            foreach (string filePath in this.Store.GetFileNames())
                files.Add(new FileItem { "FlashCardApp\\" + FileName = filePath });
            return files;
        }
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the file?

Comment: I've put the directory name in `this.Store.GetFileNames()` to retrieve the files from the directory, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the file type you need to read?

Comment: @Bas - I want to view the list of saved files. But it isn't getting the files. And i've checked, the files is existing in the directory.

Comment: people should just state a reason why they down vote -_- I dun think the 2 people who tried their best to answer deserves a down vote either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the answer to my own question.

This is how it is suppose to be:

```
private ObservableCollection<FileItem> LoadFiles()
{
    ObservableCollection<FileItem> files = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>();

    foreach (string filePath in this.Store.GetFileNames("FlashCardApp\\"))
        files.Add(new FileItem { FileName = filePath });
    return files;
}
```

By having \ after the folder name, `"FlashCardApp\\"`, it will retrieve the files from the directory.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to add an * after the file path, eg. "FlashCardApp\\\*"

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve file names, you can use `System.IO`:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt")
```

The `Directory` class is in `System.IO`.

Comment: You can remove the second parameter of GetFiles()

Comment: Directory.GetFiles doesn't really *work* when he's attempting to fetch the data from a IsolatedStorage.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:/Folder Name");
 FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.*");
 foreach(FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
 {
 //Do something
  fi.Name        
 }
```

Comment: it's on the windows phone, not on a computer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I doubth that your folder name is correct. I'll recommend you use `storeFile.GetDirectoryNames("*")` to see what the correct paths for the directory is.

Microsoft wrote a [great example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd5e2z84.aspx) I think you should try and take a look at, since there's nothing obvious wrong with your code.

Comment: if i use storeFile.GetDirectoryNames("*"), the list will show the folders. However, i want it to show the files which is inside the folders

Comment: Not quite the point. The GetDirectoryNames show you the full path. If you use GetDirectoryNames("Folder Name") what does it return to you?

Comment: it gave me the same result as GetDirectoryNames()

Comment: i'm still not sure what's wrong. I've tried GetFileNames("*") too. and it isn't working.